# Bad result expected

Tags: oracle10g, procedure

I have two tables like this

> FLUX_ISU_EQU

```
ID  NUMBER(38,0)
EQU_CODE    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
DATE_DERNIERE_MODIF DATE
```

> FLUX_ISU_EQU_AFF_TAB

```
ID  NUMBER(38,0)
EQU_ID  NUMBER(38,0)
DATE_DEBUT  DATE
DATE_FIN    DATE
TYPE_EQU    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
CODE_REGION VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
```

I have data in my tables like this:

> FLUX_ISU_EQU

[image]

> FLUX_ISU_EQU_AFF_TAB

[image]

I have a procedure like this:

```
PROCEDURE DONNEES_IS_PRESENT(equ_id IN NUMBER, isCheckDonnees IN OUT BOOLEAN) IS
nbEquipement NUMBER;
BEGIN
nbEquipement := 0;
select count(*) into nbEquipement from flux_isu_equ_aff_tab fieat, flux_isu_equ fie where fieat.EQU_ID = fie.id AND fie.id = equ_id;
  IF nbEquipement = 0 THEN
    isCheckDonnees := false;
    Pk_Compas_Util.LOG_ERROR('Pk_Compas_Flux_Isu.IMPORT_EQUIPEMENT_EAI', 'IMPORT_EQUIPEMENT_EAI', equ_id, NULL, NULL, 'Acune correspondance pour l''id '''||equ_id||''' dans la table FLUX_ISU_EQU_AFF_TAB', NULL);
  END IF;
END;
```

So, why when i execute my procedure nbEquipement = 3 instead of nbEquipement = 1.

Why..?

PS: When i do

```
select count(*)  from flux_isu_equ_aff_tab fieat, flux_isu_equ fie where fieat.EQU_ID = fie.id AND fie.id = 2;
```

I have one result

Thx.

Comment: Did you commit when you added the rows in your tables?

Comment: yes i commit when i added my datas

Comment: As far as I can see the result should be 3

Comment: If you do a Select on the identifier should return only one result instead of three.

Comment: How many rows do you get when you do:  select * from flux_isu_equ_aff_tab fieat, flux_isu_equ fie where fieat.EQU_ID = fie.id AND fie.id = 2;

Comment: I get one row when i do select * from flux_isu_equ_aff_tab fieat, flux_isu_equ fie where fieat.EQU_ID = fie.id AND fie.id = 2;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13774/discussion-between-mercer-and-sjuul-janssen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following query

```
select count(*) into nbEquipement from flux_isu_equ_aff_tab fieat, flux_isu_equ fie where fieat.EQU_ID = fie.id AND fie.id = equ_id;
```

equ_id refers to the field of the table. Since FLUX_ISU_EQU_AFF_TAB has a column equ_id. And therefor you have a join that looks like this. `fieat.EQU_ID = fie.id`

What you should do is VERY simple. Just rename the variable to IN_EQU_ID or PARAM_EQU_ID orso. And your query should look like:

```
select count(*) into nbEquipement from flux_isu_equ_aff_tab fieat, flux_isu_equ fie where fieat.EQU_ID = fie.id AND fie.id = in_equ_id;
```

Stored procedure should look like this:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DONNEES_IS_PRESENT(in_equ_id IN NUMBER, isCheckDonnees IN OUT BOOLEAN) AS
nbEquipement NUMBER;
BEGIN
nbEquipement := 0;
select count(*) into nbEquipement from flux_isu_equ_aff_tab fieat, flux_isu_equ fie where fieat.EQU_ID = fie.id AND fie.id = in_equ_id;
  IF nbEquipement = 0 THEN
    isCheckDonnees := false;
    --Pk_Compas_Util.LOG_ERROR('Pk_Compas_Flux_Isu.IMPORT_EQUIPEMENT_EAI', 'IMPORT_EQUIPEMENT_EAI', equ_id, NULL, NULL, 'Acune correspondance pour l''id '''||equ_id||''' dans la table FLUX_ISU_EQU_AFF_TAB', NULL);
  END IF;
END;
```

I think it is best if you have all your parameters prefixed with IN_ or something like that
So that you dont have the same names for your parameters as your field names